# Kafka Streams group by and concatenation

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka stream that receives records and I want to concatenate messages based on particular field.

A message in a stream looks like following:

```
Key: 2099
Payload{
  email: tom@emample.com
  eventCode: 2099
}
```

Expected Output:

```
key: 2099
Payload{
    emails: tom@example, bill@acme.com, jane@example.com
}
```

I can get the stream to run fine, I just am not sure what the lamda should contain.

This is what I have done so far. I am not sure whether I should use map, aggregate or reduce or combination of those operations.

```
final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
KStream<String, Payload> inputStream = builder.stream(INPUT_TOPIC);

inputStream
        .groupByKey()
        .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(300000)))

                                  // Not sure what to do here …..

}).to (OUTPUT_TOPIC );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be something like this

```
inputStream.groupByKey().windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(300000)))
.aggregate(PayloadAggr::new, new Aggregator<String, Payload, PayloadAggr>() {
        @Override
        public PayloadAggr apply(String key, Payload newValue, PayloadAggr result) {
            result.setKey(key);
            if(result.getEmails()==null){
                result.setEmails(newValue.getEmail());
            }else{
                result.setEmails(result.getEmails() + "," + newValue.getEmail());
            }
            return result;
        }
    }, .../* You serdes and store */}).toStream().to(OUTPUT_TOPIC);
```